# Is this RS expression standard or a hack

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using `Switch` and there doesn't seem to be an obvious `ELSE` section to the expression so I've ended up with the following but it feels a bit like a hack - is it?

It works - in that it amends the string if it is either `foo` or `bar` but any other product string is left alone:

```
=Switch(Fields!Product.Value = "foo" , "foo (incl sad)", 
       Fields!Product.Value = "bar", "bar (incl sick)",
       Cdbl(1)=Cdbl(1), Fields!Product.Value)
```

Comment: You could just use `true` instead of 1 = 1 - might read a little clearer

Comment: @Charleh put that as an answer then...definitely makes it more readable;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since someone requested it:

```
=Switch(Fields!Product.Value = "foo" , "foo (incl sad)",  
        Fields!Product.Value = "bar", "bar (incl sick)", 
        Cdbl(1)=Cdbl(1), Fields!Product.Value)
```

Would become

```
=Switch(Fields!Product.Value = "foo" , "foo (incl sad)",  
        Fields!Product.Value = "bar", "bar (incl sick)", 
        true, Fields!Product.Value)
```

Which I think is more readable - I can understand `1 = 1` but can anyone enlighten me as to what the cast to a double is for in the original code?

As far as I know, this is the only way to return an 'else' from a switch statement. Otherwise null/Nothing is returned (for c#/VB gurus respectively).

Comment: I've had some unexpected errors in connection with comparison of different types within SSRS expressions so I usually always now `cast` andy numbers to double.

Comment: what is your `null/Nothing: c#/VB` comment all about

Comment: null/Nothing are equivalent (almost!) in c#/VB, but SSRS uses VB so I just put it in there since I use c# :P (they are equivalent but I think VB lets you assign a non-nullable value type to `Nothing` and it will just default the value)

Answer (score 2):

If it works, it works.  You could also use IIF(Fields!Product.Value = "foo", "foo2", IIF(Fields!Product.Value = "bar", "bar2", Fields!Product.Value)

Comment: Funny I posted the same answer 2 hours before yours and was downvoted.  Me thinks someone is simply downvoting for no reason.  Users with > 10k rep can see it...

Comment: The internet is a fickle place.

Comment: @JonH +1 - where is it? ...did you delete it? ..."Users with > 10k can see it" ...can see what?

Comment: @whytheq - i undeleted it now...When you have enough reputation whytheq you will see deleted "answers".  That is why I said users with > 10k can see it..meaning they can see my deleted answer.

Comment: "if it works, it works" ...until it breaks; which it can if it hasn't been tested enough - therefore best to ask on SO

Answer (score 0):

You can use the switch, the other thing you could of done is use `=IIF(...)` from MSDN:

> The Iif function returns one of two values depending on whether the
>   expression is true or not. The following expression uses the Iif
>   function to return a Boolean value of True if the value of LineTotal
>   exceeds 100. Otherwise it returns False:

The other expression can include another `IIF` so you are not limited to a single `IIF`.
All RS expressions can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx

Comment: +1 (to be rebellious) In other languages `iif` is a deprecated operator that is being replaced by `if`; is there plans for this in RS? ...maybe why it originally got marked down